# Power BI Embedded use of Azure Stream analytics

Tags: powerbi, azure-stream-analytics, powerbi-embedded

Does anyone know is there a way of using Azure Stream Analytics job as a source for Power BI Embedded report?

There is other Azure data sources available, but no ASA on Power BI Desktop, while designing the Power BI report.

Answer (score 2):

It is currently not possible to use Stream Analytics as an input source in PowerBI Desktop. If you want to attach Stream Analytics directly to PowerBI you should use the web version of PowerBI. After creating a report you can publish the report to web.

[image: Publish To Web]

PowerBI will create a code for you that you can embed

[image: Embedded code]

Another possibility is to attach the output of the Stream Analytics Job to a storage type (e.g Table Storage), and use it as an input source in PowerBI Desktop. From there you can start building your reports and do whatever you would like with them.

Answer (score 0):

you can use stream analytics job source in Power bi service now hosted on Azure cloud.Even event hubs can be used as a source.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-power-bi-dashboard

Hope this helps.

Cheers,
Smathew